# Using FirePHP with Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, firephp

I'm trying to use FirePHP with Zend Framework 2, but there seems to be something missing. Here's the basic code I'm trying to run:

```
$writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\FirePhp();
$logger = new Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('FirePHP logging enabled');
```

The error  I get is "FirePHP Class not found". I was initially puzzled because I do have a FirePhp class in my Zend/Log/Writer folder. But then I saw that the class constructor requires a FirePhp\FirePhpInterface object. So I checked the Zend/Log/Writer/FirePhp folder and there's a FirePhpBridge class in there that implements FirePhpInterface, but it also requires a FirePHP instance in the constructor. I don't have any FirePHP.php file in my Zend/Log/Writer/FirePhp folder. Am I supposed to get this from somewhere else?

**Update**

I now have managed to get FirePHP working, but I'm trying to figure out how to do it in a clean way so this works. The only way I've gotten it to work is putting it in the root directory of my project and doing the following:

```
include_once('FirePHP.php');
$writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\FirePhp(new Zend\Log\Writer\FirePhp\FirePhpBridge(FirePHP::getInstance(true)));
$logger = new Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('FirePHP logging enabled');
```

I assume that normally I should be able to create a writer like so:

```
$writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\FirePhp();
```

However, where this goes wrong I believe is in the getFirePhp() function of the Zend\Log\Writer\FirePhp class. The class does this:

```
if (!$this->firephp instanceof FirePhp\FirePhpInterface
    && !class_exists('FirePHP')
) {
    // No FirePHP instance, and no way to create one
    throw new Exception\RuntimeException('FirePHP Class not found');
}

// Remember: class names in strings are absolute; thus the class_exists
// here references the canonical name for the FirePHP class
if (!$this->firephp instanceof FirePhp\FirePhpInterface
    && class_exists('FirePHP')
) {
    // FirePHPService is an alias for FirePHP; otherwise the class
    // names would clash in this file on this line.
    $this->setFirePhp(new FirePhp\FirePhpBridge(new FirePHPService()));
}
```

This is where I get lost as to how I'm supposed to set things up so that this class_exists('FirePHP') call finds the right class and new FirePHPService() also works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I supposed to get this from somewhere else?

Yes, you need to get FirePHP into your project and autoloading.

If you're using composer (and I recommend that you do), just add:

```
"firephp/firephp-core" : "dev-master"
```

(or similar) in your composer.json and update.  If you're not using composer, you should grab the firephp libs, and let your autoloader know about them.

Comment: OK, so I downloaded the FirePHP files and managed to get this working the "ghetto" way. Meaning, I did an include('FirePHP.class.php') in my bootstrap file and I can run things by creating a writer like so: $writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\FirePhp(new Zend\Log\Writer\FirePhp\FirePhpBridge(FirePHP::getInstance(true))); But I'm a bit lost on how I can actually get this working cleanly like the rest of my code which is namespaced and taking advantage of the Zend\Di module. I'm adding details in my post.

Answer (score 2):

First you should add this code to Module.php of your module

```
    return array(
        //...
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
    );
```

and here content of autoload_classmap.php

```
<?php

return array(
    'FirePHP' => realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/vendor/FirePHP').'/FirePHP.php',
);
```

FirePHP.php(renamed from FirePHP.class.php) downloaded from official site.

then you can write below code in any place of your module and it will work

```
use Zend\Log\Writer\FirePhp;
use Zend\Log\Logger;

    $writer = new FirePhp();
    $logger = new Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info("hi");
```